# i am having errors with esp32 and rfid Mfrc522 card reader

Tags: rfid, arduino-esp8266, arduino-esp32, mfrc522

I managed to make my esp32 and mfrc522 card reader work before.  but Now first i got this error,

*'/esptool.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

exit status 1

Compilation error: exit status 1*

after some research, i found out tht uninstalling and installing the library might work. I did tht..and i am sure tht i installed the proper versions of the libraries. but after this im getting multiple errors with the rfid mfrc522 card reader.

*In file included from C:\Users\akhila\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.8\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:176,
from c:\Users\akhila\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MFRC522\src\MFRC522.cpp:7:
c:\Users\akhila\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MFRC522\src\MFRC522.cpp: In static member function 'static const __FlashStringHelper* MFRC522::GetStatusCodeName(MFRC522::StatusCode)':
C:\Users\akhila\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.8\cores\esp32/WString.h:38:42: error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'const __FlashStringHelper*' in return
#define F(string_literal) (string_literal)
^
c:\Users\akhila\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MFRC522\src\MFRC522.cpp:1303:29: note: in expansion of macro 'F'
case STATUS_OK:    return F("Success.");
^*

Please tell me what i can do to get rid of these errors or if someone else has encountered this problem.

i am trying to print the rfid number of a card on the arduino serial montior.
But the program is not compiling

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a [breaking change](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/macro-f-error/1118126) was introduced in ESP core 2.0.8, downgrading to 2.0.7 worked for me.